# "Invalid option" while creating a tablespace

Tags: oracle

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this syntax:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE ACME_DATA
DATAFILE '/oracle/d02/acme/ACME_DATA_01.dbf'
SIZE 40M
EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL
AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 2M
MAXSIZE 100M
UNIFORM SIZE 128KB
SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO;
```

Error report:

```
SQL Error: ORA-02180: invalid option for CREATE TABLESPACE
02180. 00000 -  "invalid option for CREATE TABLESPACE"
```

Answer (score 5):

The `autoextend` option belongs to the datafile specification (one per datafile), not to the tablespace itself, and the `uniform` option is part of the extent management clause, so you've got a mixup there.

Try:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE ACME_DATA
DATAFILE
  '/oracle/d02/acme/ACME_DATA_01.dbf' SIZE 40M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 2M MAXSIZE 100M
EXTENT MANAGEMENT
  LOCAL UNIFORM SIZE 128K
SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT
  AUTO;
```

(Note: size units are `K`, `M`, `G`, not `KB` or similar.)

Comment: I think `SIZE 128KB` will not work. Better `SIZE 128K`